# How to detect dict name in a YAML using ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have multiple YAML files which I have to process.

E.g.:

```
   some_dict:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
```

Here the problem is that I am not aware of ("some_dict"), this name could  be anything inside the YAML. Now how do I evaluate the name of the dict using ansible?

I am using ansible 2.4.

Comment: Don't put thanks in your post, it doesn't help to make your problem more clear, so it doesn't belong. Please also consider using a spellchecker before submitting

Answer (score 0):

The play below

```
vars_files:
  some_dict.yml
tasks:
  - debug:
      var: some_dict
```

with file some_dict.yml

```
some_dict:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

gives:

```
    "some_dict": {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No. I am not aware of the value it self (some_dict).1st I have to get the dictionary name value itself from yaml. Here in this example it is "some_dict". For example if I debug the variable I should get "some_dict" as output.

Comment: I don't understand your statement " For example if I debug the variable ..." Which variable are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the variable name you don't know right?

In this case, I expect you'd need to iterate through the output of {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }} with a with_sequence: to find the key you are looking for